# Injecting $mdDialog issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to use `$mdDialog` in my angular 1.5 app and I am having some issues.  I am sure I am missing something simple, but I cannot put my finger on it.

I am declaring my app as:

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngComponentRouter', 'ngStorage', 'firebase']);
```

then in my controller:

```
var controller = function ($mdDialog) {
...
}

module.component('profile', {
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/components/profile/profile.component.html',
        controllerAs: 'model',
        controller: ['$filter', '$mdDialog', controller],
        bindings: {
            '$router': '<'
        }
    });
```

The problem is that is I try to use `$mdDialog.alert(...)` I get the following error:

> TypeError: $mdDialog.alert is not a function

The `$mdDialog` object is there, but none of the functions work.  What am I missing?  Any ideas?

Comment: is your sample code correct? Your controller function accepts one parameters but you inject two services.

Comment: OMG, this is so goofy. This did it.  I totally spaced out.  Thanks man.  Put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you inject two services into your controller. Is that what you want? $filter and $mdDialog would need to be both in your Controller function parameter declaration.